# jqplot BarRender with waterfall and bardirection horizontal

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot, gantt-chart

I am trying to build a gantt like chart using jqPlot.

I can get something similar to work with BarRenderer and waterfall set to true but I want the chart to go horizontally. As soon as I put barDirection horizontal it looks wonky.

Thanks
S